# Ngx-toaster not showing in IE,and safari

Tags: angular, core-js, ngx-toastr

I am using [ngx-toaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr) for showing alerts in my angular application

But it's not showing in IE and safari (All versions), This already addressed here and it seems like a polyfill issue https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/673.

So I've imported it into `pollyfills.ts`

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/keys'
```

But this didn't work,

core-js version: 2.5.4

ngx-toaster version:9.1.2

Angular version: 7.2.0

**UPDATE**

Here are the current `pollyfills.ts`

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
 import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
 import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
 import 'core-js/client/shim';
 import 'core-js/fn/object/keys'
```

Comment: make sure that you have imported all the pollyfills are suggested here: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#suggested-polyfills

Comment: @Buzzinga I've added all the required polyfills, please check my updated question